# Why does Crystal report give an error as "Logon failed" While connecting with MS Access database using Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, report, crystal-reports-2010

I am new to Crystal reports generation. I am using .NET framework as 4.5, Visual Studio version 2013. While creating report, i face an Error while connecting Crystal report with MS Access database as follows:

[image: **Third**]

Can somebody tell me as what's going wrong with this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly check that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually **solved** my problem by doing this:

```
1- Checking the **Microsoft Access Database Engine Version installed**
2- Changing my **Connection String** according to the Version
```